# Docker: VueJS can not resolve service name backend

Tags: docker, vue.js, docker-network

I created two container `boleto_api` and `boleto_web` the first is written in ExpressJS and the last is a VueJS application.

Created docker network named boleto and from that I started the containers.. If I ping `:ping boleto_api` inside container boleto_web I have successful

```
PING boleto_api (172.21.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from boleto_api.boleto (172.21.0.2): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.105 ms
64 bytes from boleto_api.boleto (172.21.0.2): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.091 ms
```

But in Fetch API inside VueJS

```
GET http://boleto_api:3030/pessoas/buscar/11532324723 net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

Part of code:

```
fetch('http://boleto_api:3030/pessoas/buscar/'+this.$store.state.cpf)
             .then(response => response.json())
             .then(data => {
                this.dadosCliente = data
                this.show = false;
             });
```

I dont have sure if the frontend (VueJs) will be successful to do it, if not, how to proceeded ?

Comment: This same question got asked yesterday. Is there some course going on or something?

Comment: not that I know.

Comment: I got to solve this reading this article https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/dockerizing-vue-app-with-nodejs-backend-33645f0f50ec. for who still with thar question!